# Why weigh in at instead of weigh?

Tags: idioms

Let's take this for example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porsche_919_Hybrid):

"The car's weight was reduced by 39 kg, now `weighing in at 849 kg` (1,872 lb) dry and 888 kg (1,958 lb) with driver ballast."

Why not just say `now weighing 849 kg` ?

Comment: Sounds like they want the "weigh in" bit.

Comment: I believe it's more of an "official" (act of) measurement,  rather than just a statement of fact; however, I cannot find anything about this in any dictionary definitions (which is why I'm leaving it as a comment, rather than an answer).

Comment: @Oliver Mason There must be the connotation of physical power / competition here too. 'Table-tennis balls / lace doilies weigh in at ...' would only be used in a tongue-in-cheek register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Weigh in](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/weigh_in)**

> (of a boxer or jockey) be officially weighed before or after a contest

This has been used to reference the competition that exists between car manufacturers regarding the specifications of their vehicles.

It would be perfectly appropriate to just say '**now weighing 849kg**', however this would lose some of the author's intent.

Answer (score 1):

[**Weigh In**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weigh-in)
To be officially weighed before competing in a sport, especially boxing or horse racing: 
Tyson weighed in at 245 lb for the fight.

Comment: This does not address OP's question about the broadened usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it's the notion of being 'official' that makes the difference between the two usages.

Comment: @Oliver Mason That _would_ suggest the broadened usage had the answerer included it. Manhatton makes it explicit.